# Simple html dom can find PHP script (<?php ... ?>)?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using simple-html-dom for my work. I want to get all PHP script (`<?php ... ?>`) form file using simple-html-dom.

if i have one file (name: text.php) with below code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo "This is test Text"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

then how can i get this PHP script `<?php echo "This is test Text"; ?>` form above file of code using simple-html-dom.

```
$html = file_get_html('text.php');
foreach($html->find('<?php') as $element) {
    //Sonthing code ...
}
```

i can not use like this, Is there any other option for this ?

Comment: don't understand, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Won't work with that. Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: SimpleHtmlDOM probably won't make processing instructions visible. PHPs DOM methods could. Better alternative would be the tokenizer (though requires string reconstruction), or a trivial regex.

Comment: Actually why do you want this ?

Comment: Can you please tell us more - It's unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: It's a HTML parser, not a PHP parser. You're looking for a PHP parser I guess, but whatever you're trying to do sounds misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regex.  Note that regex often is *not* advisable for parsing HTML files.  That is, it *might* be okay in this case.

This will match each instance of a PHP code block and allow you to output (or do whatever else you want) either the entire block (including the tags) or the code that is contained within the block.  See the documentation for [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
<?php

$string = <<<'NOW'
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <?php echo "something else"; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo "This is test Text"; ?>
</body>
</html>
NOW;

preg_match_all("/\<\?php (.*) \?\>/", $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $phpBlock)
{
    echo "Full block: " . $phpBlock;
    echo "\n\n";
    echo "Command: " . $matches[1][$index];
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3513320085b4fadbf3620cdf6b650aafabbbb827)